# Modity HTML within JQuery for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have the following function in Jquery which returns the correct set of information:

```
function checkAllPriceBuilderBoxes() {
    var contentzz = $("#props #itemEditor #builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr").html();
    console.log(contentzz)
}
```

`contentzz` returns the following html:

```
<input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" _type="checkbox" value="No">
```

I am looking to modify this html adding the 'checked' text at the end of the html:

```
<input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" _type="checkbox" value="No" checked>
```

I have tried the following but does not work.

```
$(contentzz).append("checked");
```

ideas?

Comment: `$(contentzz).attr("checked",true);` also you should use `$("#builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add attribute to element. use `.attr()`:

```
$(contentzz).attr("checked",true);
```

If you want the modified string after adding attribute, then you need to to overwrite contenzz string with modified string element.

```
contentzz = $(contentzz).attr('checked',true)[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: This does not seem to have worked :/

contentzz.attr("checked",true);

still returns the same HTML

<input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" _type="checkbox" value="No">

Comment: @alexjohnson: you need to to overwrite contenzz string with modified string element. like this `contentzz  = $(contentzz).attr('checked',true)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the find function and change the dom element on the page not the html string:

```
var contentzz =  $("#props #itemEditor #builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr").find('.control');
console.log(contentzz[0]);
 contentzz.attr('checked','checked');
console.log(contentzz[0]);
```

```js
    var contentzz =  $(".controlCtr").find('.control');
    console.log(contentzz[0]);
     contentzz.attr('checked','checked');
    console.log(contentzz[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controlCtr">
<input type="checkbox" class="control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.attr( attributeName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to add the `checked` attribute and the use [`.prop( propertyName )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1) to get `outerHTML` property.

```js
var contentzz = '<input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" _type="checkbox" value="No">';
contentzz = $(contentzz).attr("checked",true).prop('outerHTML');
console.log(contentzz)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contentzz = '<input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" _type="checkbox" value="No">';
contentzz = $(contentzz).attr("checked",true).prop('outerHTML');
console.log(contentzz)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery the preferred way of checking all checkboxes is:

```
$(SELECTOR).prop("checked", true);
```

If using jQuery pre 1.6 then:

```
$(SELECTOR).attr("checked", true);
```

Using JavaScript, you'd have to loop through the NodeList/HTML Collection of checkboxes or by converting the NodeList into a true array. On every iteration use this:

```
OBJECT.setAttribute('checked', true);
```

The following Snippet features two functions: `checkAllvJQ()` and `checkAllvJS()`. They both check all checkboxes of a given jQuery and JavaScript objects respectively.

## SNIPPET

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  checkAllvJQ("#builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr input");
});

function checkAllvJQ(target) {
  var tgt = $(target);
  tgt.prop("checked", true);
}


var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkAllvJS("#builderItemsList .listItem .controlCtr input");
}, false);

function checkAllvJS(target) {
  var tgt = document.querySelectorAll(target);
  Array.from(tgt, input => input.setAttribute('checked', true));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main id='props'>
  <form id="itemEditor">
    <button id='btn1'>checkAllvJQ</button>
    <button id='btn2'>CheckAllvJS</button>
    <fieldset id="builderItemsList">
      <ul class='listItem'>
        <li class="controlCtr">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="No">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="yes">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="maybe">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class='listItem'>
        <li class="controlCtr">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="No">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="yes">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="maybe">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class='listItem'>
        <li class="controlCtr">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="No">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="yes">
          <input class="control" style="" type="checkbox" data-type="checkbox" value="maybe">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```